# length of tangent to a curve passing through another point

Tags: geometry, functions, curves

Let $A$ be a point on the curve

> $\mathcal{C} : x^2+y^2-2x-4=0$

If the tangent line to $\mathcal{C}$ at $A$ passes through $P(4,3)$, then what is the **length of AP**?

Please, include a general method of approaching similar kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the circle into standard form to find our center location and radius.

$$ ( h,k)=(1,0),\, R = \sqrt5 = CT $$

Distance of center to outside point squared

$$ PC^2 = (4-1)^2+ (3-0)^2= 18 $$

$$ PT^2= PC^2-5 = 18-5= 13 \rightarrow PT= \sqrt{13} $$

[image]

Comment: Thanks It helps me a lot with your picture explanation, I understand this problem now, it is about circle !, and what I have to do with the OP length is count with the distance formula squared root of (x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2, at first I confused about it and now I understand the whole explanation, thanks for you again !

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE.Hint: first you have to find the center (o) of the curve which is a circle with equation:

$x^2-2x+y^2-4=(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2-5=0r^2$ or$(x-1)^2+(y-0)^2=5=r^2$

Where r is the radius of circle and O(-1, 0) is its center. In right triangle OAP we can write:

$AP^2=OP^2-r^2$

$OP^2=(4-1)^2+(3-0)^2=3^2+3^2=18$

$AP^2=18-5=13$  ⇒ $AP=\sqrt {13}$

Comment: Check the $x$-coordinate of your center.

Comment: does the center is (0,1) ?, btw thank you very much, your explanation is very awesome, I understand now what I have to do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

> $\mathcal{C}: x^2+y^2-2x-4=0$
>   
> $\Rightarrow x^2-2x+1-1+y^2-4=0$
>   
> $\Rightarrow (x-1)^2 +y^2=5=(\surd 5)^2$

Therefore, $\mathcal{C}$ is a circle with centre $O(1,0)$ and radius, $r=\surd 5$.

Let the tangent line to the circle $\mathcal{C}$ at the point $A$ and passing through $P(4,3)$ be $T$.

Then the perpendicular to $\mathcal{T}$ at point $A$ is a normal to the circle and passes through the centre, $O(1,0)$.

> $AO$ is perpendicular to $\mathcal{T}$ (since, it is a normal)
>   
> $\Rightarrow AO$ is perpendicular to $AP$
>   
> $\Rightarrow (AO)^2 + (AP)^2 = (OP)^2$

$AO=r=\surd5$
$OP=$ distance between $(1,0)$ and $(4,3)= 3\surd2$
$AP$ is required.

> **Pre-requisite:**
>   distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$
>   $=\surd[(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2]$

**The answer will be clearer if your proceed with an image. It is better to draw the curves(if possible) while solving such questions!**

Comment: Check your distance between the center of the circle and the point $(4, 3)$.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, finally I can understand the question, the curve is the circle !, but I still confuse about the OP distance, should we count OP with the formulas (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2 ?

Comment: @AsterZen Yes! The formula of distance between any two points. For your sake, I'll add the same in my answer!